# Printing threads in a sequence and having random sleep times for each

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to write a programme, which creates k amount of threads (in my case 6, in addition to main thread). For each thread is given a sleep time/delay of 0-6 seconds by  drawing a random lot. To each thread is also given a message (variable msg). After the delay each thread prints their message (msg) and also their serial number (like was it printed as 1:st, 2:nd, etc). I need a shared information in which the amount of prints (how many threads are printed) is updated and I also need to protect/guard access to it.

Right now it just prints the threads in random order.Like:
Thread number 6
Thread number 2
etc.

Not Thread number 1, Thread number 2, etc.

Here is a my code so far:

```java
package threadcase;

import java.util.Random;

public class Threadcase {
    static Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int k = 6;

        for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
            Threadclass s = new Threadclass("Thread number " + i, rnd.nextInt(10) + 1, k);
            s.start();
    }
}
```

```java
package threadcase;


public class Threadclass extends Thread{

    String msg = "Here is the thread";
    int k = 0;
    int delay = 0;

    public Threadclass(String msg, int k, int delay){
        this.msg = msg;
        this.delay = delay;
        this.k = k;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        // sleep certain amount of seconds/milliseconds
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000 * delay);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) { }


        System.out.println(msg);

    }

    public int randomdelay(int delay){
        int delay = Thread.sleep((long)(Math.random() * 1000));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `AtomicInteger` to act as a counter and call `counter.incrementAndGet();` to increment it in a thread safe manner.
If you want your threads to be printed in the order that you started them, they also need a field that represents their order. As for how to synchronize it, I would use the *wait and notify* feature.
Your classes would be something like this:

```
public class Threadcase {
    static Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int k = 6;
        AtomicInteger printCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);
        for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
            ThreadClass s = new ThreadClass("Thread number " + i, i, rnd.nextInt(10) + 1, k, printCounter);
            s.start();
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class ThreadClass extends Thread {

    private String msg;
    private int id;
    private int k;
    private int delay;
    private final AtomicInteger printCounter;

    public ThreadClass(String msg, int id, int k, int delay, AtomicInteger printCounter) {
        this.msg = msg;
        this.id = id;
        this.delay = delay;
        this.k = k;
        this.printCounter = printCounter;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // sleep certain amount of seconds/milliseconds
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000 * delay);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //synchronization before while to avoid race conditions
        synchronized (printCounter) {
            //the while loop takes care of errant signals
            while (id != printCounter.get() + 1) {
                try {
                    printCounter.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(msg);
        printCounter.incrementAndGet();
        synchronized (printCounter) {
            printCounter.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

You need to pass the same `AtomicInteger` to all your threads.